# Validating input with do while loop

Tags: c++, loops, do-while

I am trying to minimize hardcoding numbers into my program and allowing for users to define max and min parameters along with making sure that the input is valid.

```
#include <iostream>   

int main(){ 
    int max, A=0;
    do
    {
        std::cout << "What is the max?\n";
        std::cin >> max;
        if (std::cin.fail()) {
          std::cin.clear();      
          std::cin.ignore();
          std::cout << "not an integer, try again\n";
          continue;
        }
        if(max < -1000){
            std::cout << "That doesnt make much sense, please enter the max again.\n";
        }
    } while (max <A); \\HERE IS WHERE THE PROBLEM IS.
    std::cout << "The max number of steps are " << max <<std::endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

If A is 0 or less, the program doesn't ask for user input again. instead the program just exits the loop.
If A is 1 or more, then then the program loops until a valid input is provided.

I would like the max number to be any int number, including negatives. This is working for positive numbers, but not for maximums that are 0 or less.

Comment: do you have a question?

Comment: Fixed a missing line from isolating relevant code. I want the code to keep looping until there is valid input. I want to know how to make the code to work for any integer number for -1000, 1000.

Answer (score 1):

```
 do
{
  //ask for input      
  //input taken

} while (A>=1);
```

This will the code you have to use for the scenario described at the last line. One more point you just forget to assign any value to A according to your logic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*If A is 1 or more, then then the program loops until a valid input is provided.* - You are saying exactly what the `while` loop needs to do. Just implement it.

```
} while (A >= 1); \\If A is greater than or equal to 1 then loop until valid.
    std::cout << "The max number of steps are " << max <<std::endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

To answer your follow up question:

```
} while (A >= 1 && max <= 0); \\If A is greater than or equal to 1 then loop until valid.
    std::cout << "The max number of steps are " << max <<std::endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What if I want to allow the max number to be a negative or 0.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest writing a custom function that takes an acceptable range of min/max values as input parameters, eg:

```
int promptForInt(const string &prompt, int minAllowed, int maxAllowed)
{
    int value;

    std::cout << prompt << "\n";

    do
    {
        if (!(std::cin >> value)) {
            std::cin.clear();      
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            std::cout << "not an integer, try again\n";
            continue;
        }

        if ((value >= minAllowed) && (value <= maxAllowed)){
            break;
        }

        std::cout << "not an allowed integer, enter a value between " << minAllowed << " and " << maxAllowed << ".\n";
    }
    while (true);

    return value;
}

int main(){ 
    int max = promptForInt("What is the max?", -1000, 1000);
    std::cout << "The max number of steps are " << max << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might also help to explain what `(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')` is doing. She asked a separate question a couple hour ago about that specific `if` statement.

Comment: @GenoC I posted a comment about that on the other question

Comment: Cool, just thought it would help.